# How do I prove $\lim_{{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}} \frac{{1 - x^2 - y^2}}{{x^2 + y^2}}$

Tags: calculus

I was wondering how one would prove that the following limit does not exist:

$$
\lim_{{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}} \frac{{1 - x^2 - y^2}}{{x^2 + y^2}}
$$

So far I have tried the "setting a variable to zero and solving for the 2D limit" technique, setting y = x, and converting to polar form, but all have failed to yield the correct answer.
I thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: You're on the right track thinking about polar coordinates. What does the expression look like in polar coordinates? What does $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$ look like in polar coordinates?

Comment: What happens in those cases you mention?

Comment: When limit is infinite do you say it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case you can use the limit of a composite function and reduce it to a limit in $\mathbb{R}$. Denoting $u = x^2+ y^2$, you see that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{1-x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} = \lim_{u\to 0^+}\dfrac{1-u}{u} = +\infty.
$$